# How to add Indicators in High Stock Candle Stick Chart with Angular 5.0?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want to add indicators in my High Stock Candle Stick Chart same as the below screenshot:

[image: Indicators that candlestick highchart includes]

I am using Angular 5.0. Please suggest me a library for adding Indicators.

Currently, I've completed this much work. However, I need an indicator dropdown:

[image: Expected]

I am trying something like below:

```ts
series : [{
  name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
  type : 'line',
  id: 'primary',
  data : data
}, {
  name: '15-day SMA',
  linkedTo: 'primary',
  showInLegend: true,
  type: 'trendline',
  algorithm: 'SMA',
  periods: 15
}, {
  name: '40-day SMA',
  linkedTo: 'primary',
  showInLegend: true,
  type: 'trendline',
  algorithm: 'SMA',
  periods: 40
}]
```

But it's giving me an error:

```
CandleStickComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
```

Comment: Please provide more information, such a what you tried, where you are stuck at etc

Comment: I had used  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts for plotting candlestick graph but I want to add indicators like SMA,EMA ,WMA etc...But I dont found any demo about adding indicators for Angular.

Comment: Nothing to do with angular, simply look at the indicators docs and do what it says.

Comment: Technical indicator in Highcharts is just a series. Generate dropdown in Angular (or any plugin you want to use) and then call `chart.addSeries(indicatorOptions)`, where `indicatorOptions` is for example: `{
  type: ‘ema’,
  linkedTo: ‘main-series’,
  params: {
    period: 7
  }
}`. More about technical indicators in [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/technical-indicator-series).

Comment: I am adding var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock');
require('indicators')(Highcharts);
require('sma')(Highcharts);
var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock');
require('indicators')(Highcharts);
But its show me error like:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'highcharts/indicators' in filepath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for Angular 5 with High Charts Candle stick Chart with Indicators.You can refer below link for code:

https://github.com/mitalthakkar/candlestick-indicators

Steps to run code:
1.make npm install
2. ng serve